# Creating a new type trait in C++

Tags: c++, type-traits

I want to use a type trait to detect whether a class is a valid execution policy in my library.

```
// execution.h
namespace MyLib::execution {
    struct policy1 { ... };
    struct policy2 { ... };
    ...
}
```

I usually put all my type traits in a file:

```
// traits.h
namespace MyLib::execution { // forward declarations
    struct policy1;
    struct policy2;
    ...
}

namespace MyLib {
    template <typename T> struct is_execution_policy : std::false_type {};

    template <> struct is_execution_policy<MyLib::execution::policy1> : std::true_type {};
    template <> struct is_execution_policy<MyLib::execution::policy2> : std::true_type {};
    ...
}
```

It works, but I find it rather awkward. First, I do not like the forward declarations in traits.h. I basically have to re-declare everything. Is there a better way to handle my traits? Could I move the specializations to execution.h and only leave the primary template in traits.h? Would I run into issues later with either approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I move the specializations to execution.h and only leave the primary template in traits.h?

Yes.

---

> Would I run into issues later with either approach?

Assuming that `execution.h` depends on `traits.h`, I cannot think of any issue in particular.

Comment: ok awesome thank you. Is this the recommended way of implementing new type traits?